# how to translate \r\n to display break lines

Tags: php, html

I am really confused. I was storing text with break lines from textarea in db suddenly the text started having \r\n in it. I am using nl2br() function but it's not helping.

[my stored text in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqi74.png)

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2riHh.png)

but if I input the text with \r\n by "hand" it's just fine. I don't know what is the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you've stored literal backslashes in the database, rather than actual newline characters. Don't do that.

Comment: How could I fix that?

Comment: You don't get additional characters in your input by default, you must be doing something to inject them.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this to replace \r\n to

```
echo preg_replace('/\v+|\\\r\\\n/Ui','<br/>',$q["content"]);
```

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. The proper fix for broken data is to identify and correct the code that breaks it, not write additional code to undo it.